# Is substrate T::Hashing::hash_of(...) return a random hash?

Tags: substrate

In substrate, I have a code to get hash:

```rust
            let kitty = Kitty::<T> {
                dna: String::from("test"),
                price: None,
                gender: String::from("male"),
                owner: "there's an accountid here",
            };

            let kitty_id = T::Hashing::hash_of(&kitty);
```

Could I get the same kitty_id hash if the same kitty attribute was passed into hash_of function?

Comment: Are you calling it in a Pallet or where? It is not generally safe to call a hash function with non-random inputs, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah thanks,  I found the answer, because kitty.dna is got from a random result so this will be a random hash. Otherwise, it's predictable

Answer (score 1):

No this doesn't return a random hash. It returns the hash of the input data.